# How to change angular shift velocity on cardboard VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to change the angular shift velocity in my Google cardboard implementation on Unity. This means, if I rotate say 40 degrees, the rendered view ends up turning say 45 degrees (or 35 degrees depending on a factor I can assign).

I believe I've to play around with `var rot` here. Can anyone help me figure out how to manipulate the quaternion readings here - say for every Euler 1 degree head rotation, the rendering ends up rotating 1.25 degrees?

```
// Compute new head pose.
private void UpdateHead() {
    if (updated) {  // Only one update per frame, please.
      return;
    }
    updated = true;
    GvrViewer.Instance.UpdateState();

    if (trackRotation) {
      var rot = GvrViewer.Instance.HeadPose.Orientation ;
      if (target == null) {
        transform.localRotation = rot;
      } else {
        transform.rotation = target.rotation * rot;
      }
    }

    if (trackPosition) {
      Vector3 pos = GvrViewer.Instance.HeadPose.Position;
      if (target == null) {
        transform.localPosition = pos;
      } else {
        transform.position = target.position + target.rotation * pos;
      }
    }

    if (OnHeadUpdated != null) {
      OnHeadUpdated(gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess after 7 months you might not need this anymore.
I would say this should work.

```
private void UpdateHead() {
    if (updated) {  // Only one update per frame, please.
      return;
    }
    updated = true;
    GvrViewer.Instance.UpdateState();

    if (trackRotation) {
      var rot = GvrViewer.Instance.HeadPose.Orientation ;


      var rotx = rot.x;
      var roty = rot.y;
      var rotz = rot.z;
      var rotFinal = Quaternion.Euler(rotx*1.15f, roty*1.15f, rotz*1.15f);


      if (target == null) {
        transform.localRotation = rotFinal;
      } else {
        transform.rotation = target.rotation * rotFinal;
      }
    }

    if (trackPosition) {
      Vector3 pos = GvrViewer.Instance.HeadPose.Position;
      if (target == null) {
        transform.localPosition = pos;
      } else {
        transform.position = target.position + target.rotation * pos;
      }
    }

    if (OnHeadUpdated != null) {
      OnHeadUpdated(gameObject);
    }
```